# Emails from my server are considered as spam on hotmail

Tags: email, spam, gdpr

Well all is in the title. How to be removed from their spam list? We don't use external email provider for now. We respect emails good practices: signed email, unsubscribe link, dest email...

Here are different tests, nothing bad reported:

- https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/tokeeen.com
- https://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/tokeeen.com
- https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3atokeeen.com&run=toolpage

Can we contact Microsoft for a manuel check?